# Nginx rewritten URL fails to redirect

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, rewrite

I have been trying to redirect a specific URL of the type
`https://subdomain.example.com/story_meta_info.php?id=9483` to `https://subdomain.example.com/dash/#/story/9483`

I have tried using this rewrite rule but it keeps adding `?id=9483` at the end.

```
rewrite ^/story_meta_info\.php.* https://$host/dash/#/story/$arg_title redirect;
```

Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: The argument name is ID, where did you get arg_title? Also, Are you sure you don't get that from the upstream?

Comment: `rewrite ^/story_meta_info\.php.* https://$host/dash/#/story/$arg_id redirect;` used this and got redirected to `https://subdomain.example.com/dash/#/story/9483?id=9483`. The page opens but the extra `id` parameter gets added at the end

Comment: This is working `rewrite ^/story_meta_info\.php.* https://$host/dash/#/story/$arg_id? redirect;`. Added ? at the end

Comment: If you could put it in the answer I can accept it :)

Comment: You can post an answer yourself, too.

Comment: I can but @FlorinAsăvoaie solution helped me out. Credit should go to the original author :)

Comment: I am here to help, not to get bonus points.